# Why i get GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT?

Tags: android, opengl-es, render-to-texture

i am developing a game for android, but i my target devices are a little bit slow.
In these devices the color is showed  in a different way, in some cases red are to much opaque. 
As a solution to this I made a shader opengl correct colors according to the device. I load the textures from SD, then i do a render-to-texture to apply the shader and finally i delete the texture without the effect.
This is done once time per texture load.
The problem is that at some point my code render to texture begins to fail.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &fbo_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture, 0);
// Disable depth buffer
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);

GLint status;
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture, 0);
if ((status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
```

This works fine, but after a certain point begins to fail and always return GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT.

I have no idea because it starts to fail.

**Update**: Now i just use only one FBO for all textures loaded, however i get the a new error on my android device:

```
eglLockWindowSurface: failed to map the memory for fd=80 offs=2428928
waitForCondition(LockCondition) time out(identity=14,status=0) CPU may be pegged, trying again
```

Comment: Are you cleaning up after yourself? With `glDeleteTextures`/etc?

Comment: Yes, i am deleting the FBO but the texture(fbo_texture) was preserved throughout the game.

Comment: And it's definitely `Gen`d only once?

Comment: Why are you constantly creating and destroying the FBO? Keep it around.

Comment: It's because i need adjust the colors(nivels and tones) according to the device, so, every time that i load a new  texture i make a new FBO to make a render to texture with a opengl shader for change the colors.